# Mapping Rails routes to Ember routes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes

NOTE: This is not the same as [Ember Routes and Rails Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134789/ember-routes-and-rails-routes)

I have a single-page Ember app that lives on top of a Rails stack. Disregard the need for Rails – it's needed.

My Ember application view lives at `/ember_app`. I would like to have normal resourceful routes map to Ember routes, like so:

```
GET /home     ~> /ember_app/#/home
GET /account  ~> /ember_app/#/account
GET /login    ~> /ember_app/#/login
```

What would be the best approach for this? One thought is:

1. Rails `routes.rb` sends all requests to a single action, `ember_app#index` along with a parameter containing the name of the Ember route (as with `redirect_route: "account"`). Note `home`, `account` and `login` don't need anything data-wise from Rails, just want to redirect to that route in Ember.
2. The `ember_app#index` action stores the `route` parameter into an instance variable `@redirect_route`
3. In `ember_app.html.erb`, `@redirect_route` is interpolated and stored in a JavaScript variable `EmberApp.redirectRoute`
4. In Ember's `application_view.js` (or wherever is appropriate) we use `EmberApp.redirectRoute` to redirect on the client side, accordingly.

Does this approach sound reasonable? We could also have Rails actions for each route, and that route just renders the `index` action and passes the `route` parameter. It seems as though, however, there could (should) be a way to map Rails routes to Ember routes programmatically. We don't want to have to duplicate them, once in the Rails `routes.rb` and in the Ember `router.js`. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but it sounds like all you need is to map everything to your ember app and then let ember do the routing.

Using a wildcard route should do the trick. Just map everything to that controller, your app will be loaded and then the Ember Router will decide what to do next.

```
get '(*anything)', to: 'ember_app#index'
```

That's the way I have set up, except that I don't do it on root, mine looks a bit more like:

```
get 'application_name/(*anything)', to: 'ember_app#index'
```

Hope this helps